# oci_execute(): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

Above issue comes after login. We are changing the lowercase to uppercase for table name and table fields. we are new for oracle 19c. we are tired to learn the oracle 19c please check below code

```
function check_login($uname,$pass){

    #For Temp purpose password is not encrypt
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("USER_DETAILS");
    $where_arr=array('USER_TYPE'=>'customer','USER_LOGIN_NAME'=>$uname,'USER_STATUS'=>1);
    if($pass!=""){
        $where_arr['USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD']=md5($pass);
    }
    $this->db->where($where_arr);
    $res=$this->db->get();
    
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to trace the application and find the actual SQL statement being executed? Did you try to execute the same statement inside the database with the same logon user? There're no any details in your code (and evidence that the table actually exists), we cannot guess.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the `user_details` table doesn't exist or that the Oracle user you've logged in as doesn't have access to the `user_details` table.  It could be that you need to qualify the table name (i.e. the table exists in a different schema, you've granted the Oracle user access to the object in the other schema, but you haven't created a synonym for the object so you need to use a fully qualified object name, i.e. `owner.user_details`.